# IE条件式：[if lt IE 9]が画面に表示されてしまう

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml

以下の記載を含んだXHTMLをIEのドキュメントモードIE9で表示した場合、画面に表示されてしまいます。
ドキュメントモードIE10,IE11,Edgeでは表示されず条件式として処理されているようです。どこに誤りがあるのかご教示をおねがいします。

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and
media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <h:outputScript name="html5shiv.min.js" library="js" />
    <h:outputScript name="respond.min.js" library="js" />
    <h:outputScript name="lte-ie7.js" library="js" />
  <![endif]-->
```

**更新**
JavaEEの場合、Conditional Commentsはデフォルトではエスケープされてしまうようです。よって、IE9以下では画面に条件式が表示されます。解決策としては以下のようにエスケープを無効にするパラメタを設定することで解決しました。

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and
media queries -->
  <h:outputText
    value="&lt;!--[if lt IE 9]&gt;
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;src=&quot;#{request.contextPath}/javax.faces.resource/html5shiv.min.js.xhtml?ln=js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;src=&quot;#{request.contextPath}/javax.faces.resource/respond.min.js.xhtml?ln=js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;src=&quot;#{request.contextPath}/javax.faces.resource/lte-ie7.js.xhtml?ln=js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;![endif]--&gt;"
    escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>～<![endif]-->`は[conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)と呼ばれInternet Explorer独自の機能ですが

> **Important**  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode.

とあり、IE10以降の標準モードであれば条件式に関係なく `<!-- ～ -->` つまりHTMLコメントと見做されます。
IE9以前であれば条件式 `lt IE 9` に従って判断されます。

> ドキュメントモードIE9で表示した場合、画面に表示されてしまいます。
>   ドキュメントモードIE10,IE11,Edgeでは表示されず

とのことですが、結果から推測するに

- IE9ではブラウザーモードIE9で、質問文とは異なりドキュメントモードIE5 (Quirks)で動作している
- IE10以降ではブラウザーモードIE10などで、質問文通りドキュメントモードIE10などで動作している

となっているのではないでしょうか？ IE10からドキュメントモードの判定が変更されており

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

宣言が含まれていない場合がこれに該当します。

Comment: 回答有難うございます。私の方はIE11を使用していました。IE11の場合、ブラウザモードが存在しないのでドキュメントモードをIE9に設定しているのは確実でした。また、DOCTYPE宣言も記載していました。
結局は私のJavaEEの勉強不足が今回の原因でした。詳細は質問の更新を見てください。ともあれ、Conditional Commentsについて詳細な説明をいただきありがとうございました。